# Транспозиция и конверсия: в чем разница?

Tags: терминология

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всякая селёдка - рыба, но не всякая рыба - селёдка ©.

Конверсия = транспозиция, но транспозиция ≠ конверсия.

Конверсия - морфологическая транспозиция, а последняя вся такая разная бывает, [синтаксическая](http://www.levin.rinet.ru/ABOUT/Aksenova3.html) к примеру...

Не, а чего я буду мучиться, когда слинявшая в Париж Вероничка уже всё рассказала?..

> В ОТЛИЧИЕ от транспозиции КОНВЕРСИЯ представляет собой БОЛЕЕ УЗКОЕ
> языковое явление, иначе говоря, её можно считать транспозицией,
> имеющей словообразовательный характер.    Обязательным условием
> конверсии является ПЕРЕХОД слова из одной части в другую, так как в
> пределах ОДНОЙ части речи конверсия НЕВОЗМОЖНА.    А ТРАНСПОЗИЦИЯ в
> широком смысле — перенос любой языковой формы, например, транспозиция
>
> а) ВРЕМЕН (использование настоящего времени вместо прошедшего или будущего),
>
> б) НАКЛОНЕНИЙ (употребление императива в значении индикатива или условного наклонения),
>
> в) коммуникативных ТИПОВ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ (употребление вопросительного предложения в значении повествовательного) и др.
>
> Это лучше увидеть на примерах (это не конверсия, а транспозиция):
>
> переносное (несобственное) употребление категориально-грамматических
> форм, например употребление настоящего времени в значении прошедшего
> времени («настоящее историческое», напр., "Вчера я иду по улице и
> встречаю знакомого"),
>
> употребление наст. времени в значении буд.
> времени ("Завтра я еду в Москву"),
>
> употребление повелительного
> наклонения в значении сослагательного ("Приди он вовремя, мы бы не
> опоздали"),
>
> употребление ед. ч. в значении множественного (магазин
> педагогической книги)...

Вера - филолог экстра-класса, подробности ея рассказа **[ТУТЪ](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PMea2x5sk54J:https://otvet.mail.ru/question/90810359%20&cd=6&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)**.

Ещё любопытный фрагмент из Вики([педии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))):

> ...Существует и более широкое понимание конверсии (оно отстаивается, в
> частности, в работах И. А. Мельчука): она может рассматриваться как
> любая смена синтагматики (сочетаемости) языкового знака (необязательно
> слова).
>
> При такой трактовке случаями конверсии можно считать, в частности,
> употребление слов одной части речи в функции других, например в
> русском:
>
> моё второе *я* (местоимение → существительное); *большое спасибо*
> (частица → существительное), *столовая* (прилагательное →
> существительное; см.: субстантивация).
>
> Такие процессы отличаются от конверсии в узком смысле не очень
> существенно: главным образом различие заключается в степени
> регулярности.